# Using Bumblee (Graphics Drivers) with Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run build using graphics drivers by using optirun (Bumblebee) from IDE (Netbeans, Eclipse)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264487/how-to-run-build-using-graphics-drivers-by-using-optirun-bumblebee-from-ide-n)

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with Bumblebee for the nvidia optimus graphics card.  Everything works fine so far, so when I type `optirun glxspheres` the graphics card fires up fine.

The problem I am having is with Eclipse when I build a Libgdx Desktop project it uses the old graphics card.  I run eclipse using `optirun ./eclipse` but for some reason when I build the project it still runs using the old graphics card.

Any ideas, why this might be happening or how I might be able to fix it?